# Microsoft Search Server

Tags: search, search-engine, microsoft-search-server

How do you retrieve the most popular search terms programmatically from Microsoft Search Server?

Answer (score 2):

1. You will need to [enable search usage reporting](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262541.aspx).
2. Extracting the popular search terms doesn't look like it's supported OOB. So you can check out [this article](http://jopx.blogspot.com/2008/04/extending-usage-analysis-reporting-in.html), or this v1 code on [CodePlex](http://www.codeplex.com/usage/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=14372) to let you do this.